# SQL php update based on occurence

Tags: php, mysql

i'm a new programmer and I am trying to create my sql for my php.

It's for generating statistics and one of the fields on the table needs to be updated(I think), however I have no idea how to update a field based on the number of times an answer occurs. The $type should be updated after the insert based on the value that comes from the $f fields. The possible values in the $f fields are 1-10.  So if 1 occurs the most often in the fields between 1-10, the $type should be then updated to 1.

```
INSERT INTO `p`.`f` 
(`pk_frage`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`, `f6`, `f7`, `f8`, `f9`, `f10`, `type`, `fk_user`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, '$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4', '$f5', '$f6', '$f7', '$f8', '$f9', '$f10', NULL, '$pk_user');


UPDATE `p`.`f` SET type =  ??
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get here.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You should consider changing your table design. It is not good

Comment: start with the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right. I changed the Table and removed all of those f fields and decided to do all of the calculations in the php itself.